# Is any $S_4$-invariant function also $S_6$ invariant?

Tags: permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, symmetry, symmetric-functions

Consider the following embedding of the permutation group $S_4$ inside $S_6$:

$\sigma \in S_4 \to \tilde \sigma \in S_6$, where
$$
\tilde \sigma\big(a_{12},a_{13},a_{14},a_{23},a_{24},a_{34}\big)=\big(a_{\sigma(1)\sigma(2)},a_{\sigma(1)\sigma(3)},a_{\sigma(1)\sigma(4)},a_{\sigma(2)\sigma(3)},a_{\sigma(2)\sigma(4)},a_{\sigma(3)\sigma(4)}\big),
$$
where we agree that the variables $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$, so for instance if $\sigma(1)=2,\sigma(2)=1$, we think of $a_{\sigma(1)\sigma(2)}$ as $a_{12}$.

> **Question:** Does there exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^6 \to\mathbb{R}$, such that $f$ is $S_4$-invariant but not $S_6$-invariant?

i.e. I want
$$
f\big(\tilde \sigma(a_{12},a_{13},a_{14},a_{23},a_{24},a_{34})\big)=f(a_{12},a_{13},a_{14},a_{23},a_{24},a_{34})
$$
for every $\tilde \sigma \in S_4 \subset S_6$ (and every $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{6}$), but that

$$
f\big(x_{\tau(1)},x_{\tau(2)},x_{\tau(3)},x_{\tau(4)},x_{\tau(5)},x_{\tau(6)}\big) \neq f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6),
$$

for some $\tau \in S_6\setminus S_4$ and $(x_i) \in\mathbb{R}^{6}$.

---

I guess we can begin with some non-invariant function, and average it over $S_4$; this probably won't be invariant under the full group $S_6$, generically. Does this work for $$f(a_{12},a_{13},a_{14},a_{23},a_{24},a_{34})=a_{12}+a_{13}?$$

Is there an easy way to compute the averaging of this function? I think the action of $S_4$ on pairs $(i,j)$ is transitive or something like that and this should help.

However, my group theory is rusty, and $S_4$ has $24$ elements...is there a shortcut?

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy argument for why this is $S_4$-invariant?

Comment: Oh, I think I sort of see. Any pair is paired with a complementing one. But you need to show different "pair-couples" are mapped to different couples, right? Is that trivial? i.e. we need to show that $\{\{\sigma(1),\sigma(2)\},\{\sigma(3),\sigma(4)\}\} \neq \{\{\sigma(1),\sigma(3)\},\{\sigma(2),\sigma(4)\}\}$ etc, so any permutation indeed permutes the set of complementing pairs.

Comment: OK, that is rather trivial! So I guess this concludes the question!

Comment: FWIW:  the average of $a_{12}$ over $S_4$ is $\frac{1}{6} (a_{12} + a_{13} + a_{14} + a_{23} + a_{24} + a_{34})$, since there are exactly four elements of $S_4$ sending $\{1, 2\}$ to any other unordered pair.  The average of $a_{13}$ is the same thing, so by linearity the average of your suggested function $a_{12} + a_{13}$ over $S_4$ is in fact $S_6$-invariant.  But averaging e.g. $a_{12} a_{13}$ or $a_{12} a_{34}$ will work (and the latter agrees with @ThePhoenix's answer up to scalar multiplication).